# Prove or find a counterexample of the following: $(A'\cup B) \cap (B' \cup C) \subseteq (A' \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$(A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup C)  \subseteq  (A' \cup C)$

then $(A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup C) \cap (A' \cup C)  =  (A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup C)$

Let's say I define the Universal set to be $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ , $A=\{1,3,5\}$ , $A'=\{2,4\}$ , $B=\{2,4\}$ , $B'=\{1,3,5\}$ , $C=\{\phi\}$. Is this correct for  a counterexample?

If it isn't, can you give me a working example.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: You have your $A, B, C$ what is stopping you from checking the equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \in (A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup C)$, then $x \in A' \cup B$ and $ x \in B' \cup C $. If $x \in A'$ or $x\in C$, ok. But If $x \in B$, then $x \notin B'$ therefore $x\in C$ and $ x \in A' \cup C.$ The same If $x \in B'$.So the result is true.

Comment: $B'$ is the complement of $B$ ... so if $2 \in B$, then $2 \not \in B'$

Comment: @Bram28 ahhh, I didn't know that this notation was complementary, I'll change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First: If you want to define $C$ as the empty set, you have to write $C = \emptyset$ or $C = \{ \}$, but if you say that $C =\{ \emptyset \}$, then you are saying that $C$ is a set that contains one elemnet, that being the empty set.

Anyway, let's go with $C =\{\}$, and see if your choice of $A,B,C$ works as a counterexample:

$A' \cup B = \{ 2,4 \} \cup \{ 2,4 \} = \{2,4 \}$

$B' \cup C = \{1,3,5\} \cup \{\}=\{1,3,5\}$

So that means $(A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup C) = \{2,4\} \cap \{1,3,5\}=\{\}$

On the other hand: $A' \cup C= \{2,4\} \cup \{\}=\{2,4\}$

So, clearly $(A' \cup B) \cap (B' \cup C) \subseteq A' \cup C$

So no, this is not a counterexample.

Ok, so maybe try some other counterexamples. And, in doing so, I would recommend starting with smaller sets, e.g. where the domain contains just one or two elements. If some choice of $A,B,C$ doesn't work, try to understand *why* it doesn't work: should you maybe add an element to $A$? Remove an element from $B$? In other words: try to *systematically* construct a counterexample. After a while, you may not only come to suspect that there is no counterexample, but also obtain some pretty good insight why there may not be a counterexample. And, that could be a good starting point for creating a proof that the claim is in fact true, rather than false.

Comment: thankyou for the tips!